# Java convert list of string to list of objects

Tags: spring-boot, collections, java-8

In order to increase performance, my API is going to receive an array of string that I need to convert to an array of objects.

My array looks like this:

```
List<String> listPersons = ["1, Franck, 1980-01-01T00:00:00, 00.00", "2, Martin, 1989-01-01T00:00:00, 00.00"];
```

How could I easily convert it to a list of Persons (List), if possible using Java 8 so I don't have to create a loop and manually explode the String?

```
class Person {
 private Integer id;
 private String name;
 private Date dateOfBirth;

 // getter and setter
}
```

Ideally I'd like to automate this directly using SpringBoot - Using a custom converter such as:

```
public class StringToPersonConverter implements Converter<String, Person> {

    @Override
    public Person convert(String from) {
        String[] data = from.split(",");
        return new Person(Integer.parseInt(data[0]), data[1], new Date(data[2]));
    }
}
```

Declaring the converter:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addConverter(new StringToCreditCardConverter());
    }
}
```

And ideally map it from my controller directly?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/insertPersons", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String savePersons(@RequestBody List<Person> listPersons) {}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to detect my converter and it's throwing an error ;/
Any idea? Thanks

Comment: could be problem that you trying to convert to `List of persons`, not to the `person`.
also from your question I understand that you get single string (`RequestBody`) with data for multiple `Person`'s while you convert only to single one.

Comment: If an exception is thrown, please share the stacktrace associated to.

Comment: Use JSON as your string format and you won't even need to do anything special; just declare the parameter type as `List<Person>` and spring will do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

As a side note : `String[] data = from.split(",");` will not work with `,` as character separator because values use this character, for example : `1980-01-01T00:00:00, 00.00`.

> In order to increase performance, my API is going to receive an array
>   of string that I need to convert to an array of objects.

Here is a non answer.  JSON is a format that consumes very few memory (literally characters) to convey the structure.   So you don't need and even don't have to concatenate in a single String distinct information that here represent difference `Person`.
Designing an API that waits for unstructured JSON/text and restructuring the JSON/text in the backend in an anti pattern : it is not more efficient, it makes the API unclear and add boiler plate code both in the front and the back end.